# Elliptic Curve and SECP256K1

Tags: ecdsa, secp256k1

Just for curiosity, considering that there is a server communicating with other machine (local machine let's call it). If we have the two public keys from Local and Server and we know that Private and Public key from local machine are generated using secp256k1. Would there be any possibility to get the private key of Local? How? By considering Twist attacks?

Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

> Would there be any possibility to get the private key of Local?

No. If the keys have been generated correctly (sufficient entropy etc) and independently (whether on the same machine or on different machines) then knowledge of one private key leaks no information on the other.